# How to set focus on a specific radio button within an Option Group

Tags: radio-button, focus, ms-access-2013

When tabbing to an Option Group containing radio buttons (Yes No) I want to set the focus to the first entry in the option group but it is being set to the second radio button.  I do not want to actually set the value, just the focus.  Preferably, I want to do this through Forms, not VBA.

Comment: Are you sure that the second option is lower on the page or in line with the  first option? Tab will move to the option closest to the top of the option frame.

Comment: I am not seeing a way to mark your answer as accepted. If it has been posted as a comment, please adjust as I would like to give you credit.  I have been banging my head against this problem (and web hunting) for longer than I care to admit.  Your suggestion has been tested and works!  Thank you.   [Grumble, grumble to Access since the layout difference in side by side buttons was minimal or I would have adjusted the buttons for cosmetic reasons anyways.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the second option is lower on the page or in line with the first option? Tab will move to the option closest to the top of the option frame.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was not finding this answer anywhere on the web or in manuals.  Seems like a trivial matter but it was very important to those using my form for data entry and was driving me crazy trying to find! What a great experience posting here for the first time. Hopefully this may help someone else out there too.